# transform table in datagrid - simple class registry application

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm making some simple application to managing grades of students. I have one problem with datagrid with grades.

I want to display data in this format in datagrid:
[image]

Table in database looks like this:

[image]

I want to somehow transfrom table to format where 'TypeName' will be in column names, and what is important, it can repeat, because Student can have 2 grades from the same type.

It has to be only one row because it is datagrid for only one student.

I guess I should use Pivot or Unpivot function, but I'm not so good in this, and I read that function use aggregating, which I don't want to use.

Comment: show us what you did so far ?

Comment: You want sample of code? To be honest in this part I have nothing for now, because I don't know which method will be best for me. I'm looking for some easy way to do it. I don't know if this more database/sql problem or maybe is it easy way to do it from visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with a basic pivot view, something like this:

```
    SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
       lastname, grade, subjectname, typename
    FROM table
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(grade)
    FOR [typename] IN (test1, answer, listening, speaking, etc.....)
)AS pvt
```

Then you need to do something like a sum in the grade field for example.

Comment: Thanks, it;working really fine, but still have problem with sum function, because I want to have grade in separated column